# What is blacklist file in JRE

Tags: security, java

I downloaded JRE and inside jre/lib/security/, there is a file called blacklist. The content is like following:

```
# JNLPAppletLauncher applet-launcher.jar  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: 5Bo5/eg892hQ9mgbUW56iDmsp1k= 

# 7066583
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: x17xGEFzBRXY2pLtXiIbp8J7U9M=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: ya6YNTzMCFYUO4lwhmz9OWhhIz8=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: YwuPyF/KMcxcQhgxilzNybFM2+8=  

# 7066809
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: dBKbNW1PZSjJ0lGcCeewcCrYx5g=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: lTYCkD1wm5uDcp2G2PNPcADG/ds=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: GKwQJtblDEuSVf3LdC1ojpUJRGg=  

# 7186931
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: 0CUppG7J6IL8xHqPCnA377Koahw=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: 3aJU1qSK6IYmt5MSh2IIIj5G1XE=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: 8F4F0TXA4ureZbfEXWIFm76QGg4=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: B1NaDg834Bgg+VE9Ca+tDZOd2BI=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: bOoQga+XxC3j0HiP552+fYCdswo=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: C4mtepHAyIKiAjjqOm6xYMo8TkM=   
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: cDXEH+bR01R8QVxL+KFKYqFgsR0=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: cO2ccW2cckTvpR0HVgQa362PyHI=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: D/TyRle6Sl+CDuBFmdOPy03ERaw=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: eJfWm86yHp2Oz5U8WrMKbpv6GGA=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: g3mA5HqcRBlKaUVQsapnKhOSEas=   
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: HSPXCvBNG/PaSXg8thDGqSeZlR8=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: iMHjGyv5gEnTi8uj68yzalml8XQ=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: jd5MvBoWh7aHiUa1v15lqXVQ9y4=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: L0l3WOuMNWujmXo5+O/GtmGyyYk=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: l4meuozuSFLkTZTS6xW3sixdlBI=   
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: l93uYyDZGyynzYTknp31yyuNivU=   
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: lbhLWSopUIqPQ08UVIA927Y7jZQ=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: nv5+0eBNHpRIsB9D6TmEbWoNCTs=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: obWCTaz3uOZwDBDZUsbrrTKoDig=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: odqJCMnKdgvQLOCAMSWEj1EPQTc=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: OfQZHjo8GK14bHD4z4dDIp4ZFjE=    
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: PVAkXuUCgiDQI19GPrw01Vz4rGQ=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: Q9HXbUcSCjhwkgpk5NNVG/sArVA=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: qMVUh9i3yJcTKpuZYSFZH9dspqE=    
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: TFYT30IirbYk89l/uKykM6g2cVQ=    
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: trhKo6XiSGxRrS//rCL9e3Ca6D4=    
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: uWffvhFaWVw3lrER/SJH7Hl4yFg=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: vSd+kv1p+3jrVK9FjDCBJcoy5us=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: WX77FlRyFyeUriu+xi/PE1uLALU=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: WyqHV02O4PYZkcbidH4HKlp/8hY=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: Y82nn7CFTu1XAOCDjemWwyPLssg=  

# 8002218
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: saJIx2dYM4ac+paV09g7hyvF7rs=  
SHA1-Digest-Manifest: hYV/Hs2xEIHeidB+9ZVjAtTBr/g=
```

Can anybody tell me what is this file for. I am sure it has something do to with the security, however I can not figure it out, nor can I find out anything from google. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/blacklistfeature.html

Comment: Thank you, I think that explains everything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look the explanation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/blacklistfeature.html